# Enable Intercom push notifications in a Meteor web app

Tags: javascript, meteor, intercom, intercom.js

We use Intercom in our Meteor app. We only call Intercom in Javascript like `Intercom('boot')` for instance (as described in their documentation for [single page web apps](https://developers.intercom.com/docs/single-page-app)).

This all works fine so far, except the push notifications. The [documentation](https://developers.intercom.com/docs/cordova-phonegap-push-notifications) assumes Intercom is installed directly into a Cordova app.

Has anyone managed to get intercom push notifications to work on Android / iOS with a Meteor app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you should know I haven't tested this myself, but I am familiar with both Meteor and Intercom. That said, here are my thoughts on a path to success:

First, you would want to add this to your mobile-config.js file:

```
App.setPreference('intercom-app-id', 'xxxxxxxxxx');
App.setPreference('intercom-ios-api-key', 'ios_sdk-xxxxxxxx');
App.setPreference('intercom-android-api-key', 'android_sdk-xxxxxxxxx');
```

Then, you can use the Cordova functionality something like this:

```
    if (Meteor.isCordova) {
        // define values for userId and phoneNumber...
        intercom.registerIdentifiedUser({userId: userId,phone:phoneNumber});
    }
    ...
```

I'm not entirely sure how you're trying to use push notifications, but let me know your thoughts on this or if this helps. Thanks!

Comment: I should add, from there, you can begin to utilize these methods: https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/cordova-phonegap-push-notifications